# How to serialize java classes with jackson when one depends on the other through an id field and not a direct reference

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, jersey

I'm currently developing REST web services in Java with Jersey and I have a question regarding including details from a related model class in the JSON response returned by my endpoint.

My Student and Promotion model classes currently look like this:

```java
public class Student {
    private Long idStudent;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Gender gender;
    private String mail;
    private Long idPromotion;
}

public class Promotion {
    private Long idPromotion;
    private String name;
    private Boolean colorEnabled;
    private String fontColor;
    private String textColor;
}
```

I would like to modify the Student class to include the details of the Promotion class in the body of the JSON response returned by my getStudents() endpoint using annotations instead of a wrapper or an additional serialization class.

Here's an example of what I'd like to do using something like this @Reference annotation (it doesn't exist, it's just to illustrate what I'd like)

```java
public class Student {
    private Long idStudent;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Gender gender;
    private String mail;
    @Reference(Promotion.idPromotion)
    private Long idPromotion;
}

public class Promotion {
    private Long idPromotion;
    private String name;
    private Boolean colorEnabled;
    private String fontColor;
    private String textColor;
}
```

I would like to know if it's possible to achieve this using annotations and some sort of binding rather than using a wrapper or additional serialization class.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's not achievable without an additional serialization class. If you add annotation then also you need to register the class based on the annotation it behaves. Instead, you should use the `Promotion` class in the `Student` class.

```
public class Student {
    private Long idStudent;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Gender gender;
    private String mail;
    private Promotion promotion;
}

public class Promotion {
    private Long idPromotion;
    private String name;
    private Boolean colorEnabled;
    private String fontColor;
    private String textColor;
}
```

If you use the same class for deserialization then you can create the `Promotion` constructor with `idPromotion` argument. So in JSON if you pass only id then it will create a `Promotion` object with `idPromotion` set.